# context menu for 8 buttons, with 2 options edit and delete

Tags: android, contextmenu

I want to use context menu for 8 buttons in one of the activities, long pressing any button should show two options   `edit` and `delete`.

I have gone through a few examples available on the web, but they all show just a single button and its context menu. I have 8 buttons and I am able to implement context menu for the first button. I dont know how can i get it done for all the buttons.

here is a part of my code

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit Account");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete Account");
}
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Action 1") {
        function1(item.getItemId());
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Action 2") {
        function2(item.getItemId());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is what i got from a tutorial. I am not sure of what `item.getItemId()` is? is this the id of the button that was longpressed? if not how should i implement my task

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

In `onCreateContextMenu` the parameter `View v` is the view that activated the context menu. So I define a `gloabl View` and copied `v` in `onCreateContextMenu` to that global view which can be used later on